# change in value running total of time between

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a program that periodically records details of a users mobile data connection (signal strength, network technology type, etc) to a single table in PostgreSQL. The relevant fields in the table are;

```
networkmedium.id
networkmedium.date_time
networkmedium.medium_type
```

An example table may look like;

```
0  |  2013-07-26 08:00:01  | 3G
1  |  2013-07-26 08:00:02  | GPRS
2  |  2013-07-26 08:00:06  | 3G
3  |  2013-07-26 08:00:10  | 3G
4  |  2013-07-26 08:00:16  | GPRS
```

I'm trying to get from this data the total duration spent on a particular medium type (i.e. GPRS, 3G etc), and I'm having difficulty.

In the above example I'd need the time difference between r1 and r0, r2 and r1, r3 and r1, r4 and r3, and then sum'd together grouped by medium_type, but I'm stuck how best to go about this.

Thanks in advance,
Trev.

Comment: I don't get why r3 and r1, or why not (r2-r1) or (r3-r2). What's the *duration* of a connection?

Comment: Similarly, I really don't get the logic of your row selection and comparison. Can you flesh out the example a little and add a sample of the output you'd expect to get from the sample input? Also: PostgreSQL version?

Comment: Yes, edited the description; r2-r1 as well, but not r3-r2 as the type has not changed.

Although, I'd not thought of that, it would be enough to work out the time difference between a record and the previous and then add that into the sum. That would actually simplify it quite some.

Comment: can't you simply add a column and save the difference from the new inserted row and the previous one during the record registrations?

Comment: To flesh out the example, I'd like to see results of
GPRS_total = 4 (seconds) (r2-r1)
3G_total = 11 (seconds) ((r1-r0) + (r3-r2) + (r4-r3))

Comment: Yes, adding a new column would be possible. It doesn't help for the existing data I have however, but I think that's the way forward. Thanks.

Comment: This hardly makes sense: `the time difference between r1 and r0, r2 and r1, r3 and r1, r4 and r3`. Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
with CTE1 as
(
    select
        *,
        lead(date_time) over (order by date_time asc) as next_date_time
    from networkmedium
    order by date_time asc
)
select C1.medium_type, sum(date_part('second', C1.next_date_time - C1.date_time))
from CTE1 as C1
group by C1.medium_type

MEDIUM_TYPE |    SUM
--------------------
GPRS        |      4
3G          |     11
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6bb75/23)

more complex approach

```
with CTE1 as
(
    select
        *,
        lag(medium_type) over (order by date_time asc) as prev_medium_type
    from networkmedium
    order by date_time asc
), CTE2 as
(
    select *, row_number() over(order by date_time) as row_num
    from CTE1
    where prev_medium_type <> medium_type or prev_medium_type is null
)
select C1.medium_type, sum(date_part('second', C2.date_time - C1.date_time)) as cnt
from CTE2 as C1
    left outer join CTE2 as C2 on C2.row_num = C1.row_num + 1
group by C1.medium_type
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6bb75/21)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's OK to take r3-r2 as well, it would give the same results, no? If that's the case, then I think this does the job. *Haven't tested* though:

`SELECT t.medium_type, t.sum(duration)
FROM (
  SELECT n2.date_time - n1.date_time as duration
  FROM networkmedium n1 INNER JOIN networkmedium n2 on n2.id = n1.id+1
) as t
GROUP BY medium_type`

Comment: It is really bad to rely on sequence `id`. It can (and will) have gaps.

Comment: Basically true, but: (1) there is no schema in this question, so I can't tell whether this is really a sequence or something the code generates. (2) there are cases where it's OK (like when you never delete or update, only insert, and all backups are full table dumps with re-create). (3) there needs to be *some* way to specify order to events, I assumed for the sake of this question that was it.

Comment: It is ok to use this id's to set the order of events. But you can NEVER rely on sequence to be gap less. You do not need any updates or deletes to add gaps to sequence. Simple rollback or sequence caching will do.